# Excel VBA IE automation - can't click on a button that already gets focused correctly

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I use a macro to open a page using IE, enter a value in the search box and then click on the GO button. I can focus on the GO button successfully, but the click doesn't work.

The goal is to open the new page and then grab the link to the page it leads to. (...BondCenter/BondDetail.jsp?ticker=C77821&symbol=ZUAN.GA)

```
    '''Function to search a value and click GO button

    URL = "http://finra-markets.morningstar.com/MarketData/Default.jsp?sdkVersion=2.37.0"

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate URL

    WaitFor IE
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3)

    IE.document.getElementById("ms-finra-autocomplete-box").Value = "ZUAN.GA"

    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

    Max = 25
    For j = 0 To Max
         If IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input").Item(j).getAttribute("type") = "submit" Then
            If IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input").Item(j).getAttribute("value") = "GO" Then
               Set Button = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input").Item(j)

                  'The GO button gets successfully focused
                  Button.Focus

                  'Method#1 below does not click on the Button successfully
                  Button.FireEvent ("onchange")

                  'Method#2 below does not click on the Button
                  Button.FireEvent ("onclick")

                  'Method#3 below does not click on the Button
                  Button.Click

                  Exit For
             End If
         End If
      Next

    ''' Function to wait for IE
    Sub WaitFor(IE As Object)
        While IE.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the html you will find there is an event listener for `mousedown` on `Go` button . If you create and fire that event you will get the desired results.

Example event listener:

[image]

---

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer, url As String, evt As Object

    url = "http://finra-markets.morningstar.com/MarketData/Default.jsp?sdkVersion=2.37.0"
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 url
        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            .querySelector("#ms-finra-autocomplete-box").Value = "ZUAN.GA"
            Set evt = .createEvent("HTMLEvents")
            evt.initEvent "mousedown", True, False   
            .querySelector("[value=GO]").dispatchEvent evt
        End With

        Do While .document.url = url: DoEvents: Loop

        MsgBox .document.url
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's still not working. The macro gets stuck on the "Do While .document.url = url: DoEvents: Loop" part, since the .document.url doesn't change to the new page that we navigated to and still gives the original url. I switched it with Application.Wait and no matter how long I wait it still gives the original Url, as if we never left the first page.

Comment: Just tested and it runs fine. Did you run exactly as is?

Comment: Yes, I ran it as is and it never shows a messagebox. I delete out the Do While line and it gives me "http://finra-markets.morningstar.com/MarketData/Default.jsp?sdkVersion=2.37.0". I add in a Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 8) line to make sure the page loads fully and it still gives the same message.

Comment: Not sure what else to suggest. It runs perfectly every time for me. I assume you are not using a proxy and that manually you can perform these actions just fine?

Comment: I am not using a proxy and I can perform it manually. However, I kept running the macro and closing IE and trying it again, and it gave me the right url twice out of many attemps! I think maybe there is a problem with my excel or interexplorer.

Comment: Perhaps try it on another machine.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try with another machine. I also wonder if it could be a reference that I might be missing apart from MS Internet Controls.

Comment: Nope. That is the only required reference.

Comment: The same problem existed in another machine on the same network, but then I changed .Visible to False and it solved the issue!

Comment: Interesting. :-)